# Can I become eligible to receive free Windows 10 upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, upgrade, windows-10

My PC was installed with Windows 7 Pro full licence, now windows 8.1 enterprise.

Through a development programme, I then attained MSDN membership for a year and decided to upgrade to windows 8.1 enterprise for free. (Perhaps ultimate would have been a better choice at the time).

*Enterprise is not eligible for a free upgrade to Windows 10.*

Is there a way, a relatively painless way of becoming eligible for a Windows 10 upgrade?

Will any of these choices work? If I succeed, will I then become eligible for the upgrade? Or have I missed the boat?

- Downgrade my windows 8 enterprise to windows 7 pro. (have not looked into the detail)
- Clear PC and install windows 7 pro. Timely to resetup.

Last resort is to just buy the Windows 10 upgrade. Again, probably cannot upgrade from enterprise and would have to clear PC using windows 7 as the upgrade.

Comment: Reinstall W7 and activate, then upgrade to 10, will work. I don't see any other way.

Comment: Will the reinstall keep all my settings (mainly)?

Comment: No, reinstall to windows 7 will not keep your settings from 8.1. You  have option change 8.1 to pro or ultimate version by order new 8.1 key. You also can hack it, but not think it legal http://henkhoogendoorn.blogspot.com/2015/06/downgrading-windows-81-from-enterprise.html

Comment: You also can install windows 8.1 pro over enterprise(key required), that will save most settings.

Comment: @Valamas yes if you choose that during setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better option is to re-install Windows7 and Upgrade to Windows10 using USB pendrive or CD.

You can Download windows10 iso and prepare bootable USB/CD using Media Creation tool. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install

No need to wait until you get the upgrade notification.

Comment: On a spare drive i did this and it is now windows 10. I plan to set it up in parallel and then use the samsung SSD tool to transfer it to my SSD.

Answer (score 2):

If your PC had Windows 7 before you should have the license key. Reinstall Windows 7, then re-activate it and wait for the Windows 10 upgrade notification.

I just did something similar for one of my laptop which was not eligible for upgrade.